# Netbeans Xdebug Windows 10 waiting for connection

Tags: xdebug, netbeans-8

Netbeans 8.2 I get the dreaded "waiting for connection"

I know the setup is correct because I have

1. Loaded the correct version of the xdebug extension uising the official flow chart method.
2. The port forwarding is correctly specified from my PC to port 9000
3. my php.ini file has the following settings

xdebug.remote_connect_back=1

xdebug.remote_enable=1

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp

xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.remote_port=9000

xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"

output_buffering=Off

4. In Nebeans Options / PHP / Debugging the port is 9000 and the session ID is netbeans-xdebug

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of investigation, I turned off the Windows Defender "Private" Firewall and Netbeans Xdebug worked i.e. stopped "waiting for connection" and went to the appropriate line in the code.

There is a Netbeans IDE rule for TCP in the incoming firewall, but it is only set for public, it needs to be set for private as well.

Hope that helps someone